# Как передать значения чекбоксов формы в php

Tags: php, email, form

Форма:

```
<form>
    <input id="v-1" name="p-of[]" type="checkbox" value="v-1" >
    <input id="v-2" name="p-of[]" type="checkbox" value="v-2" >
    <input id="v-3" name="p-of[]" type="checkbox" value="v-3" >
</form>
```

Обработка:

```
foreach( $_POST["p-of"] as $p_of){
    $p_of_d .= $p_of;
}

$message = '                    
    <table> 
        <td>'. $p_of_d .'</td>
    </table>
';
```

На почту приходит либо только одно значение чекбокса либо вообще не приходит не чего.

Comment: если чекбокс не отмечен - то значение не передается

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$p_of_d = '';
foreach( $_POST["p-of"] as $p_of){
    $p_of_d .= $p_of;
}
if($p_of_d === ''){
   $p_of_d = 'Ничего не выбрано'; // Тут свой текс, в случае если не выбрали
}

$message = '                    
    <table> 
        <td>'. $p_of_d .'</td>
    </table>
';
```